# Select multiple rows into a single row

Tags: sql, select, hana, hana-sql-script

I have a table with the columns "Sequence-ID", "Event-ID", "Value"

To one sequence belongs up to 5 events and each event has one value
e.g.:

```
|Sequence-ID | Event-ID | Value |
|------------|----------|-------|
|1           |         1|      7|
|1           |         2|      2|
|1           |         3|      5|
|1           |         4|      9|
|1           |         5|     12|
|2           |         1|     15|
|2           |         2|      8|
|2           |         3|     10|
|2           |         4|     21|
|2           |         5|     17|
```

How can I select each sequence into one row, separated with semicolon?

```
|Sequence-ID |Value        |
|------------|-------------|
|1           |7;2;5;9;12   |
|2           |15;8;10;21;17|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use STRING_AGG(col1)

```
   select Sequence-ID , STRING_AGG(Value , ';')  AS newValue
    from table
    GROUP  BY Sequence-ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use STRING_AGG function?

http://scn.sap.com/thread/3469848

http://scn.sap.com/thread/3575156

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with STRING_AGG function, here is SQL query:

```
SELECT ID, STRING_AGG(Value, ';')  AS Names
FROM TAB
GROUP BY Sequence-ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
SELECT Sequence-ID, string_agg(Value::text, ';'::text) from table group by Sequence-ID
```